# SSIS: TNS listener was not given service_name in connection_data

Tags: oracle, ssis

Requirement: I need my SSIS (part of SQL 2012), installed on Windows 8 machine, to connect to Oracle server to extract some data. The oracle version is 11.2. Oracle 32 bit drivers have been downloaded and installed on the system. I am now getting this error - TNS listener was not given service_name in connection_data.

Connecting to SSIS under .NetprovidersforOledb\Oracle provider for oledb

Data source- (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HOSTNAME)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SER‌VICE_NAME=DATABASENAME)))

Comment: actual ORA error number is?  Can you test the connection from SSIS?

Comment: Got it! Machine reboot was required after oracle 32 bit driver installation.